# Android Studio Files Backup on Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, backup

When Android studio is installed in Linux, there are several supporting files which are downloaded by Android studio. I wish to keep a backup of the entire Android studio installation media or installed files in such a way, so that every time I have to install it in any Linux computer, I can do it offline. The main Android studio installation media is easy to keep a backup of but how can we find out what more was downloaded and installed by it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not keep the installation file, instead better back-up the installation directory including the `android sdk` and `android ndk` installation directory (check where those directories were created).

Furthermore there is the `~/.gradle` directory in your home directory which contains all the gradle related cached files.

Regarding the `~/.AndroidStudio3.0` directory in your home dir I am not sure what it contains, but it looks like there are also cached downloaded jar files.

At last you should backup the `~/.android`. It contains mostly generated files, however for example the signing keys are very important.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you mean if I copy and then paste those few folders in the same location in any new computer then my android studio should work there ? I have not checked but I feel there must be more !locations where android studio downloads / installs / stores files like in `./local`

Answer (score 0):

You need to backup the following directories:

```
$HOME\.android
$HOME\.AndroidStudio3.0
$HOME\.gradle
```

In addition to the directory where Android Studio was installed.